# Display next/previous post title

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I want to display the next/previous post title as well as the image currently working

**HTML**

```
<div class="cover boxcaption">  
                <?php $nextImg = get_post_meta($nextPost->ID, "project-thumb", $single = true); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $nextURL; ?>" class="view-project"><?php echo str_replace('src', 'width="128px" height="78px" src', $nextImg); ?>View Project</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

if i understood you i think its just like a **NEXT** and **PREV** paging functionality. you just need to display next post title on **NEXT** button and previous post title on **PREV** button. i dont think its bit of hard task..

Thanks.